# How to show the value of line only when user touch at a point in line?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am using [Charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) in my project to show line chart. Till now i did this far :

[image]

but want to show the max or min value when user touches a any point in the red line like this:
[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: yValues, label: "Subscribers")
    set1.drawCirclesEnabled = false //hides the peek circles
    set1.mode = .cubicBezier
    set1.lineWidth = 4
    set1.setColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1))
    set1.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
    set1.drawValuesEnabled = true
    set1.valueTextColor = .systemGray
    
    let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set1)
    data.setDrawValues(false)//hides the peek circle values
    
    lineChartView.data = data
```

Comment: It is called `Marker` in the library. You can take a look at the official [examples](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo-iOS/Swift/Demos/LineChart1ViewController.swift#:~:text=let%20marker%20%3D%20BalloonMarker,chartView.marker%20%3D%20marker). [Documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/markerview/) is only available in Android version, which is almost the same as the iOS version.

Comment: @RickyMo can you please tell me how to put the circular dots on X and Y axis that is shown in the second image?